# Emulate webpage and send as a live video to user

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, emulation, simulation

Example:
User comes to my page demo.html
at that page, he will see a video (or canvas) of example.com

when he moves and click on a mouse we will send coordinates on example.com - record what happened and show to the user at demo.html as video

Simple- demo.html will emulate example.com

[image]

Is that possible and how I can build that?

p.s. PLease don't tell me to use iFrame because of CORS and iFrame is not a solution for my problem.

Comment: This question is confusing. It's not clear what behavior you are expecting.

Comment: I just want to simulate example.com on my page demo.html so when user click on move mouse to send that coordinates to server where execute example.com then return what happend as a live video to user

Comment: like https://www.browserling.com/

Comment: @ToddChaffee Think of this like user is on 1st. PC and look at demo.html and example.com is on 2nd PC When I move mouse to 1.st PC to reflect that on 2.nd PC and what happend on 2.nd PC to send as a live video to 1.st PC